# How can I prevent corruption of binary characters when calling response.text() in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to retrieve a `.woff` font file from a url, convert the bytes to hex and then store the file in the new encoded format.

Currently, I have a function which does just this however the file somehow get's corrupted somewhere inbetween.

The function which I have currently is as following:

```js
function getfont(url) {
    fetch(url).then(function(response) {
        return response.text();
    }).then(function(text) {
        var hex = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
            hex.push(text.charCodeAt(i).toString(16));
        }
        console.log(hex.join(''))
    })
}
```

I have checked the response before encoding and do not seem to see anything obvious which clues me to how the file is getting corrupted after it is being encoded and I have also checked that the font stored at the url works beforehand.

How would I go about fetching the `.woff` file and storing it as an encoded string without any corruption and being able to use the file after decoding it?

Comment: `response.text()` is the problem, use a binary access method like blob or arrayBuffer.

Comment: also you need leading zeros so that each hex byte is 2 chars. `hex.push( ("00"+text.charCodeAt(i).toString(16)).slice(-2));`